# How many projects can we create within a solition in visual studio 2013?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

[Solution Explorer Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqeP5.jpg)
How many projects can we create? Have any limitation?
In Visual Studio, we can create one or more projects under a single solution.

Thanks,
Tofael Ahmed

Comment: I don't think there is a limit. I've seen solutions with more than 200 projects in them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recommended number of projects in Visual Studio Solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529907/recommended-number-of-projects-in-visual-studio-solution)

Comment: You can have as many projects as you want inside your solution

Comment: Any reason to ask [such questions](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0c1ae64d-f293-4f6d-ae4c-8e7398c2401b/maximum-projects-in-a-visual-studio-solution?forum=tfsversioncontrol)? I bet here are developers who work with VS for 20+ years and they never ever think about it.. Like you never think about maximum number of windows in Windows.. or maximum number of tabs in browser.. It's *virtually* unlimited, but it is definitely limited by environment (e.g. memory amount, x64/x86, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I am aware there are no official limitations other than your system limitations.  However, there are many opinions on what constitutes an 'appropriate' number.

I have worked with solutions with just one project and others with well over 100 projects.

In my personal opinion I think the determining factor is separation of concerns - if  the projects are used as ways of splitting code into more manageable pieces but the code is still interdependent then I think that is a good reason to have multiple projects.

If you have multiple concerns (e.g. Application, Support Libraries, Tests) you might will consider separate solutions to be appropriate.

In the end, the decision is yours and the limits are effectively your system limitations and your opinions.