# What is the max number of assemblies that can be deployed as a part of a Web API?

Tags: c#, .net, webapi

What is the max number of assemblies that can be deployed as a part of a Web API?

Example: Can a web API solution with 200 projects, be built and deployed without reaching any sort of .net limit?

Comment: If there is a limit, it's probably more than you're likely to reach. And you would deploy a project (and its dependencies), not a solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53759580/3181933

Comment: This feels like a XY Problem (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why are you asking?

Comment: If you need to exceed a likely limit, your architecture will have very serious problems.